# Sensitivity of pure strategy Nash Equilibrium

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

It is well known that the Nash Equilibrium means that players will not better off by deviating from the equilibrium. If some irrational player deviates, its cost may increase. I am wondering does there exist a numerical description of the cost change between the strategy to cost change.
For example, in two different games, in the first game, if the player deviates, its cost increases by 10. But in the second game, its cost increases by 20. Does this mean the first game is more robust or insensitive to deviations?

Thanks

Comment: I have a similar question to this too. Do you have an example payoff matrix to better communicate your concept of cost?

Comment: Example of what you have in mind would really help here

Comment: Battle of sexes 1: [[(3,2), (0,0)],[(0,0), (2,3)]]  ;   Battle of sexes 2: [[(4,1), (0,0)],[(0,0), (1,4)]]. Player A picks which game they are playing and makes a decision (4 choices). Player B picks between left and right. This game has multiple nash equilibrium. So I'm trying to see if there is a cost of sorts to picking a certain nash equilibrium vs another equilibrium. How robust the nash equilibrium is when compared to another? Is this related to your question?